# Best API for event creation

Tags: api, facebook-events

I'm new to the api game, and I'm trying to figure out the best starting point for my case.

I need to include a feature on a website to allow a customer to create a facebook event on their own facebook profile and invite their friends.

Which is the best option for this: web or opengraph?

**EDIT:** just another feature I need: the ability to feel personal data using the customer's facebook profile (OAUht??)

Thanks

Comment: "web or opengraph?" -- What is `web`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Facebook's Graph API to create events. Details on how to create an event on behalf of a user can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events). Note: you'll need to request the `create_event` permission from your users, which brings us to OAuth...

Yes, you'll need users to authorize your application so that it can access their personal data. For this you need to implement the client-side Facebook OAuth flow. This involves showing users a Facebook OAuth dialog that describes you app and what permissions it wants from them. In order to use your application they must click the 'allow' button to authorize your app and return the access token that you need to access their Facebook account. Details (including examples) can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).